# What do (G) and (S) mean in samba's parameter configuration?

Tags: networking, samba, documentation, parameter

In the official documentation of [Samba](https://www.samba.org/), the [smb.conf(5)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) page has an "Explanation Of Each Parameter" section.

For some parameters, two possible values (either `(G)` or `(S)`) are shown at the end of the name, but nothing for others.

What do `(G)` and `(S)` mean in samba's parameter configuration? (and *empty/nothing*?)

Answer (score 2):

From the smb.conf man page, second paragraph under PARAMETERS:

> The letter G in parentheses indicates that a parameter
> is specific to the [global] section. The letter S indicates that a parameter can be
> specified in a service specific section. All S parameters can also be specified in the
> [global] section - in which case they will define the default behavior for all services.